# Better way to validate a URL in PHP

Tags: php, url, filter, validation

I've been reading various posts on Stack Overflow to try and find an ideal way to validate a URL in PHP.  My research has come up with three possible solutions, however, none of them are ideal.

The three methods mentioned are regex, `filter_var ($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)` and `parse_url ()`.  The problems with the first approach are already well known, and the most comprehensive validation regex I could find spanned pages.  The filter_var function built into the PHP filtering extension appears to have faults, such as treating a url like http://... as valid.  The parse_url method is using a function that was never intended for URL validation and therefore can't be depended on for this task.

Are there any other options regarding URL validation in PHP that I may have missed?

Comment: Grab a class that does it already. Zend_Validate_Hostname for isntance.

Comment: When you say URL validation, do you mean one that resolves to a page/response? Or a correctly formed one? Are you looking to validate only full URLs or relative URLs (like `google.com`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about you combine `filter_var` (which basically is a regex check that spans pages) with additional regex check for cases you don't think are covered well by it?

Comment: I've just been revisiting this problem, and am finding FILTER_VALIDATE_URL to be utterly broken.  It can't validate urls that contain IPV6 addresses.  I'm thinking I need an approach that just avoids filter_var altogether.

Comment: Or you might want to fill in a feature request on php.net, so that IPv6 support is added. Or both.

Comment: Seems someone thought of that already.  https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54629 has been open for 8 months.  Between this and the problems I ran into with FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL I'm getting the impression that php's built in filters are best avoided.

Comment: They're unfortunately obsolte in many cases. Never or rarely updated since introduction, while at the same time formats they're supposed to validate have moved forward.

Comment: Yeah, PHP does have the feeling of a project that's bogged down these days, doesn't it?

Comment: Actually it moves along better than 2-3 years ago, when it practically stalled. Still it has some trouble finding enough skilled devs to implement new features as well us update existing ones.

Comment: Yeah, I'm glad to see it moving again and 5.4 has some potentially nice features.  Still, you'd think an 8 month old bug would have seen a bit more activity by now.

Answer (score 1):

I ussually use `parse_url()` for check/validate url (in most case, i need to determine whether the url is already a valid url or a relative url)

```
if (parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME) != '')
{
   // Url is absolute
}
else
{
   // Url is not an absolute url, and therefore, need more validation...
}
```