# Validate whether a variable's contents is a domain

Tags: php, string, validation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to validate domain name in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755144/how-to-validate-domain-name-in-php)
>   [Better way to validate a URL in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134545/better-way-to-validate-a-url-in-php)

How do I check, if `$variable` is a site address?

Like, for this it should give `true`:

```
$varialbe = 'http://google.com';
```

For this `false`:

```
$variable = 'this value can be anything, but we know its not a domain';
```

Comment: You should probably consult this strange little fellow named Google. Ask him about `php url validation`, he might know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`filter_var`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) function (also see [types of filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php)) provided by PHP:

```
$is_url = filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
```

Comment: It has some problems but is a good enough solution for his need, IMO

Comment: @LuckyMurari: Indeed, you might be best off combining some further validation, but it's a good starting point none-the-less. The comments in the PHP manual will point out the quirks, or some of them anyhow. (The PHP manual is quite underrated and needs to be promoted more.)

Comment: @nikc -- The documentation has it's own quirks though; inconsistencies in method signatures, missing noteworthy edge cases that become all to apparent very quickly, etc. Either way, good answer; I've not used the filter functions yet anywhere.